# Objective-C continuous horizontal scrolling text

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

is it possible to create continuous horizontal scrolling for UILabel in Objective-C.
The code in HTML would look like this, so you can get a better idea what I'm talking about.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Scrolling text goes here</marquee>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its a little unconventional but easily possible. All you have to do is call a selector method on a timer, and update the contents of the  UILabel with each timer expiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in control that provides this functionality. You may want to take a look at the open source project [`MarqueeLabel`](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel), which is a subclass of `UILabel` that adds support for this effect.